# invoke method of @facescomponent of composite component

Tags: jsf, composite-component, backing-beans

I need to invoke a method of backing component(@facescomponent) of composite component. I see others do this in articles but none of them has ever worked for me.

this how I invoke:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite">

<cc:interface componentType="formField"/>

<cc:implementation>
    <h:commandButton value="doIt" action="#{cc.myAction}" ></h:commandButton>
</cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

and this is the backing component.

```
@FacesComponent("formField")
public class Field extends UICommand implements NamingContainer {

public Field() {
}

@Override
public String getFamily() {
    return UINamingContainer.COMPONENT_FAMILY;
}
public String myAction() {

    System.out.println("in action");//not printed
    return null;
}
}
```

Shouldn't `myAction` method be invoked? What did I do wrong?

Comment: I used your code as noted above with a minor correction, and it printed out the `in action` value in my server logs. I used JSF 2.2 on Apache Tomcat 8.0.9. I don't see an error. Do you have any further information?

Comment: well, that was mounts ago.I don’t even remember what happened to that code. thanks for reply anyway.

Comment: check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913791/invoke-actionlistener-of-backing-component-in-composite-component

Answer (score 0):

you do an invoke for property, for method need to use:
action="#{cc.myAction()}"